Why do the moles in my Whack-a-Mole game never pop up?
I am trying to make a Whack-a-Mole game (codepen ) as part of a project on an online coding course. This is what the end result should look like, but in my code, the moles never pop up:

I only wrote the HTML and CSS -- the JS was completely written by the instructors of the course.


let score = 0;
let molesLeft = 30;
let popupLength = 3000;
let hideTimeout;
let clickable = false;

function popUpRandomMole() {
  if (molesLeft <= 0) {
    document.querySelector('.sb__game-over').classList.remove('sb__game-over--hidden');
    return;
  }

  const moleHeads = document.querySelectorAll('.wgs__mole-head');

  if (moleHeads.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const moleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moleHeads.length);
  const moleHead = moleHeads[moleIndex];

  clickable = true;

  moleHead.classList.remove('wgs__mole-head--hidden', 'wgs__mole-head--whacked');

  molesLeft -= 1;
  document.querySelector('.sb__moles').innerHTML = molesLeft;

  hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => hideMole(moleHead), popupLength);
}

function hideMole(mole) {
  clickable = false;
  mole.classList.add('wgs__mole-head--hidden');

  setTimeout(popUpRandomMole, 500);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setTimeout(popUpRandomMole, 0);

  const moleHeads = document.querySelectorAll('.wgs__mole-head');
  for (let moleHead of moleHeads) {
    moleHead.addEventListener('click', event => {
      if (!clickable) return;

      score += 1;
      document.querySelector('.sb__score').innerHTML = score;
      popupLength -= popupLength / 10;

      clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
      hideMole(event.target);

      event.target.classList.add('wgs__mole-head--hidden');

    });
  }
});
.wgs {
  width: 320px;
  height: 241px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wgs__mole-head {
  width: 188px;
  height: 178px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
}

.wgs__mole-hill {
  width: 320px;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 131px;
}

.wgs__mole-head--hidden {
  width: 188px;
  height: 178px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  margin-top: 241px;
  transition: margin-top 0.25s;
}

.pf {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / repeat(4, 1fr);
}
<div class="pf">

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

  <div class="wgs">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill">
  </div>

</div>



Here is what I did in the HTML and CSS:

I used position: absolute for the images of the mole and the hill relative to their container.
Made a "visible" class and a "hidden" class for each mole.
The hidden class uses transition: margin-top 0.25s and overflow: hidden for the mole to hide.
Put the moles in a grid so they would be in 2 rows and 4 columns.
Assigned the hidden class to all the moles.

The course instructions say once you assign the hidden class to all the moles, the JS should start working, but it doesn't.
When I try to run the code as it is, nothing happens. I've checked my code multiple times and even tried doing the project from scratch step by step, and I haven't figured out what could be stopping the JS from doing its thing.
When I change the hidden class to the visible class and add this to the JS, it toggles the mole heads between those two classes, getting it to pop up and down. This is just to test out the transition, though.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  setInterval(() => {
    const moleHeads = document.querySelectorAll('.wgs__mole-head');
    for (let moleHead of moleHeads) {
      moleHead.classList.toggle('wgs__mole-head--hidden');
    }
  }, 1000);

});


Any help would be appreciated!

The reason your moles are not shown is because there is a margin top defined but this doesn't get set anywhere to 0. Also .wgs__mole-head is looked up in the beginning of the JS and there is a check if it is empty. However you don't have any mole with this class in the beginning.

If you edit your code in, create ONE snippet with all the code instead of seperating them into 3 snippets..

You seem to be querying for an element with the class sb__moles, which doesn't appear to exist?

Please never link "here" or "this".

You have .sb__moles and .sb__score missing from your html code and you are using them in javascript which is causing the problem. Also, only one of the mole has a class .wgs__mole-head which will cause issue as the moleHeads node-list will only have one mole in it which will keep popping up again and again. While you want a different mole each time. There are other missing classes as well like .sb__game-over .sb__game-over_hidden, I have commented that part out in your js as it doesn't have anything to do with the issue.
You have used const moleHead while this keeps changing everytime. Use let instead of const. Also, moleHeads is being defined twice in your code, if you use something globally then you should define it in the beginning of your code.


let score = 0;
let molesLeft = 30;
let popupLength = 3000;
let hideTimeout;
let clickable = false;
const moleHeads = document.querySelectorAll('.wgs__mole-head');

function popUpRandomMole() {
  //if (molesLeft <= 0) {
  //document.querySelector('.sb__game-over').classList.remove('sb__game-over--hidden');
  //return;
  //}

  if (moleHeads.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const moleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moleHeads.length);
  let moleHead = moleHeads[moleIndex];

  clickable = true;

  moleHead.classList.remove('wgs__mole-head--hidden', 'wgs__mole-head--whacked');

  molesLeft -= 1;
  document.querySelector('.sb__moles').innerHTML = molesLeft;

  hideTimeout = setTimeout(() => hideMole(moleHead), popupLength);
}

function hideMole(mole) {
  clickable = false;
  mole.classList.add('wgs__mole-head--hidden');

  setTimeout(popUpRandomMole, 500);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  setTimeout(popUpRandomMole, 0);

  for (let moleHead of moleHeads) {
    moleHead.addEventListener('click', event => {
      if (!clickable) return;

      score += 1;
      document.querySelector('.sb__score').innerHTML = score;
      popupLength -= popupLength / 10;

      clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
      hideMole(event.target);

      event.target.classList.add('wgs__mole-head--hidden');

    });
  }
});
.wgs {
  width: 320px;
  height: 241px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wgs__mole-head {
  width: 188px;
  height: 178px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
}

.wgs__mole-hill {
  width: 320px;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 131px;
}

.wgs__mole-head--hidden {
  width: 188px;
  height: 178px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  margin-top: 241px;
  transition: margin-top 0.25s;
}

.pf {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / repeat(4, 1fr);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pf">
    <div class="sb__moles"></div>
    <div class="sb__score"></div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head wgs__mole-head--hidden" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>

    <div class="wgs">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0ujXUJ0.png" class="wgs__mole-head--hidden wgs__mole-head" alt="mole_head" />
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JE9Ry2y.png" class="wgs__mole-hill" alt="mole_hill" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



